# How to install SHOGUN(machine learning library) on Mac OS?

Tags: macos, shogun

Can anyone tell me the step-by-step process to install shogun on mac os. I have tried macports, brew install. Seems like nothing is working out.

Have installed shogun using macports succesfully, but not able to import in python. Can anyone please tell me what is going wrong.

Answer (score 2):

**updated**:

in order to install the latest shogun, simply do:

```
brew install shogun
```

**original answer**:

<strike>I'm developing shogun on OSX. Currently 4.1.0 is part of brew. I'm working on getting release 6.0.0 into brew, but in the meanwhile if you want to use the latest version you'll need to compile it on your own.</strike>

For the dependencies of the library simply run

```
brew deps shogun
```

install those packages as well as **cmake**. for the actual compilation follow the manual at http://shogun.ml/install#manual`

Comment: i have used brew to install shogun. but not able to import shogun as modshogun. I am a beginner, please help me in what i need to do make this work once the install is done.

Answer (score 0):

As of 10th September, 2023, `brew install shogun` does not work - the package is no longer present. `port install shogun` is unable to generate the necessary dependencies and is an old version anyway (2.1.0_24). `port install shogun_devel` installs version 4.0.0_21, but again fails dependencies.

One remaining option is to install version 6.1.4 manually from source:
https://github.com/shogun-toolbox/shogun/blob/develop/doc/readme/INSTALL.md#manual-requirements